# create list of String from file names in provided directory

Tags: java, scala, file-io

probably my question is rather obvious. Would like to look on the one directory and createthe the List of the String, where each string represents the file name stored in given direcotry, e.g. List("file1.csv", "file2.csv", "file3.csv").

I use the function which creates list, but it's list of Files (not Strings) and includes full paths (not only the file names).

```
import java.io.File

def getFileNames(path: String): List[File] = {
  val d = new File(path)
  if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
    d
      .listFiles // create list of File
      .filter(_.isFile)
      .toList
      .sortBy(_.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",""))
  } else {
    Nil // return empty list
  }
}
```

Thank you for all the ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the return type of `getFileNames` to`List[String]` and use `map(_.getName)` like so

```
def getFileNames(path: String): List[String] = {
    val d = new File(path)
    if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
      d
        .listFiles // create list of File
        .filter(_.isFile)
        .toList
        .sortBy(_.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",""))
        .map(_.getName)
    } else {
      Nil // return empty list
    }
  }
```

Make sure `.map(_.getName)` is the last in the chain, that is, after `sortBy`.

[better-files](https://github.com/pathikrit/better-files#unix-dsl) would simplify this to

```
import better.files._
import better.files.Dsl._
val file = file"."
ls(file).toList.filter(_.isRegularFile).map(_.name)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use getName method

and as  Tomasz pointed out, filter and map can be combined to collect as following

```
def getFileNames(path: String): List[String] = {
  val d = new File(path)
  if (d.exists && d.isDirectory) {
    d
      .listFiles // create list of File
      .collect{ case f if f.isFile => f.getName }// gets the name of the file  <--
      .toList
      .sortBy(_.getAbsolutePath().replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]",""))
  } else {
    Nil // return empty list
  }
}
```

Comment: The `filter` followed by `map` can be combined using collect `collect{ case f if f.isFile => f.getName }`

Comment: Thanks! A small comment: the output type should be changed to the List[String].